# How can I iterate a SimPy simulation in parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, simpy

I have a SimPy model that returns a random result which I would like to replicate many times. Each replication is independent so to make it faster I'd like to run them in parallel. I've tried Python's [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html), [Pathos multiprocessing](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos), and joblib [Parallel](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html), but with each approach I get the same error: `TypeError: can't pickle generator objects`. Is there any way to avoid this error and run the simulation in parallel?

SimPy relies on generators as explained [here](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpy_intro/basic_concepts.html), so avoiding them isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error describes the problem fairly well. Somewhere among the objects you are sending to the child process, a generator is lurking, presumably among the function arguments. Is it possible to convert this generator to a list?

For example, the following raises the error you mention:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def firstn(n):
    k = 0
    while k < n:
        yield k
        k += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(2)
    print(p.map(firstn, [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

But this one works:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def firstn(n):
    k = 0
    while k < n:
        yield k
        k += 1

def wrapped(n):
    return list(firstn(n))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(2)
    print(p.map(wrapped, [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: In SimPy, every process is a generator that yields simulation events, so they're not really possible to avoid.

Comment: I see. Well, there might still be clever ways to go around them. I edited my answer with an example.

Comment: I had something like this in mind but I couldn't quite piece it together. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Your example works fine when I run standalone functions in parallel, but I run into the same error when I try to use class methods. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was able to break out one of the methods into a function to get it to work for my application, but I'm curious why class methods can't be passed to `map`.

Comment: The technical answer is that it's because they cannot be pickled. For a detailed explanation of what can be pickled and why, please see https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled.

Class methods interact with the instance state, so the results might be unpredictable if they could be executed in parallell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the Environment from scratch **inside the new process**, and take care to use only vanilla types as arguments to be mapped in a `Pool`. Here is a reworked carwash example (the one from the `simpy` documentation) that runs 4 parallel simulations with different seeds and prints how many cars were washed in each case.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import simpy
import random


NUM_MACHINES = 2  # Number of machines in the carwash
WASHTIME = 5      # Minutes it takes to clean a car
T_INTER = 7       # Create a car every ~7 minutes
SIM_TIME = 20     # Simulation time in minutes


class Carwash(object):
    """A carwash has a limited number of machines (``NUM_MACHINES``) to
    clean cars in parallel.

    Cars have to request one of the machines. When they got one, they
    can start the washing processes and wait for it to finish (which
    takes ``washtime`` minutes).

    """
    def __init__(self, env, num_machines, washtime):
        self.env = env
        self.machine = simpy.Resource(env, num_machines)
        self.washtime = washtime

    def wash(self, car):
        """The washing processes. It takes a ``car`` processes and tries
        to clean it."""
        yield self.env.timeout(WASHTIME)


def car(env, name, cw):
    """The car process (each car has a ``name``) arrives at the carwash
    (``cw``) and requests a cleaning machine.

    It then starts the washing process, waits for it to finish and
    leaves to never come back ...

    """
    with cw.machine.request() as request:
        yield request
        yield env.process(cw.wash(name))


def setup(env, num_machines, washtime, t_inter):
    """Create a carwash, a number of initial cars and keep creating cars
    approx. every ``t_inter`` minutes."""
    # Create the carwash
    carwash = Carwash(env, num_machines, washtime)

    # Create 4 initial cars
    for i in range(4):
        env.process(car(env, 'Car %d' % i, carwash))

    # Create more cars while the simulation is running
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(random.randint(t_inter - 5, t_inter + 5))
        i += 1
        env.i = i
        env.process(car(env, 'Car %d' % i, carwash))


# additional wrapping function to be executed by the pool
def do_simulation_with_seed(rs):

    random.seed(rs)  # This influences only the specific process being run
    env = simpy.Environment()  # THE ENVIRONMENT IS CREATED HERE, IN THE CHILD PROCESS
    env.process(setup(env, NUM_MACHINES, WASHTIME, T_INTER))

    env.run(until=SIM_TIME)

    return env.i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    seeds = range(4)
    carwash_pool = mp.Pool(4)
    ncars_by_seed = carwash_pool.map(do_simulation_with_seed, seeds)
    for s, ncars in zip(seeds, ncars_by_seed):
        print('seed={} --> {} cars washed'.format(s, ncars))
```

Comment: What you **cannot** do easily is fork an existing Environment mid-flight with deepcopy or pickle for the purpose of tweaking its parameters and doing different scenarios without re-running everything, ideally in parallel. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58415397/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-copy-a-class-instance-that-contains-simpy-processes