# What is the easiest way to copy a class instance that contains SimPy processes?

Tags: python, deep-copy, simpy

I'm trying to create a copy of a class instance that I can simulate without affecting the original instance of the class. I've tried using `copy.copy`, but I run into this problem:

```py
system.simulate(until=100)

print(system.env.now) # prints 100

copy_of_system = copy.copy(system)
copy_of_system.simulate(until=200)

print(copy_of_system.env.now) # prints 200
print(system.env.now) # prints 200, but should print 100
```

When I use `copy.deepcopy` I get `TypeError: can't pickle generator objects`. Is there any effective way to create an independent copy of the `system` object?

Answer (score 0):

One way of having an existing `simpy.Environment` take several different paths of execution in parallel would be to use `os.fork()` when you're done setting up the Environment. You then can, for example, leverage the interprocess communication primitives in `multiprocessing`, such as `Queues`, etc, for collecting the interesting results of the different simulations. This requires writing a fair amount of boilerplate associated with manual forking, but it can be more than worth it.

NB: `os.fork()`, that I know of, is available only under Unix-like OSes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create two instances of the your model, each in their own environment, and just run one longer then the other.  You can use a common seed for any random generators.  You can use a process with a time out to make changes at your branch points.  Of course the longer the warm up, the slower this method will be.